# RequestFactory & reverse with pk (must be called with either an object pk or a slug)

Tags: django, django-testing

So I have this code:

```
request = self.factory.get(reverse('portal-edit-automation', args=(self.rule.id,)))
response = EditAutomation.as_view()(request)
```

And if I set a pdb break point right before it and do:

```
(Pdb) reverse('portal-edit-automation', args=(self.rule.id,))
u'/portal/automations/edit/1/'
```

I get the expected response.

So why am I getting this when running the test suite?

```
AttributeError: Generic detail view EditAutomation must be called with either an object pk or a slug.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call the view with the request and the primary key, for example:

```
EditAutomation.as_view()(request, pk=self.rule.id)
```